# C# WPF RichTextBox как переопределить вывод текста?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Как сделать чтобы строки выводились не вниз , а наоборот чтобы текст опускался а новая строка вставлялась на первую позицию, 
как в окне чата , последнее сообщение всегда вверху , а остальные строки скролятся в низ

Comment: Так вам может нужен не richtextbox, а обычный текстбокс для ввода сообщения и листовой контрол для чата?

Comment: Вот тут https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/tree/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.ChatModule я делал чат на wpf, поглядите, может вам поможет

Comment: `text.Text = text.Text.Insert(0, "TEST");` ну или `text.Text = "TEST" + text.Text; `

Comment: tym32167  большое спасибо , сейчас изучаю Ваш материал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во FlowDocument, контейнером для которого является RichTextBox, новую строку вверх можно добавлять так:

```
// Инициализация документа скорее всего будет снаружи
if (RichTextBox.Document == null)
    RichTextBox.Document = new System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument();

// Добавляется первая строка
if (RichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Count == 0)
{
    RichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Новая строка")));
    return;
}

// Вторая и следующие строки добавляются перед первой
RichTextBox.Document.Blocks.InsertBefore(RichTextBox.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock,
    new Paragraph(new Run("Новая строка вверху")));
```

Comment: Геннадий П   не  такое не пойдет ,  мне именно в RichTextBox надо

Comment: Это и есть добавление в RichTextBox

Comment: gor Nazarenko   -  большое спасибо ,  Ваше решение  я даже сократил до одной строчки и все хорошо работает ,   а  насчет " не такое не пойдет , мне именно в RichTextBox надо"  это я  написал  "Геннадий П"